# Code From Book Doesn't Log Me in Automatically PHP & MariaDB

Tags: php, mariadb

I register my user, but when I log in after registration I'm told to log in again. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// include function files for this application
require_once('bookmark_fns.php');
session_start();

//create short variable names
if (!isset($_POST['username']))  {
  //if not isset -> set with dummy value 
  $_POST['username'] = " "; 
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
if (!isset($_POST['passwd']))  {
  //if not isset -> set with dummy value 
  $_POST['passwd'] = " "; 
}
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

if ($username && $passwd) {
// they have just tried logging in
  try  {
    login($username, $passwd);
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
  }
  catch(Exception $e)  {
    // unsuccessful login
    do_html_header('Problem:');
    echo 'You could not be logged in.<br>
          You must be logged in to view this page.';
    do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
    do_html_footer();
    exit;
  }
}

do_html_header('Home');
check_valid_user();
// get the bookmarks this user has saved
if ($url_array = get_user_urls($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
  display_user_urls($url_array);
}

// give menu of options
display_user_menu();

do_html_footer();
?>
```

I tried using this member.php code but it doesn't work the way I want it to. Please help me get the book example to work properly and log me in right after registration

Comment: When I search for code similar to yours I find a book that was first published in 2008. If I'm wrong, ignore this and accept my apology. Although there's nothing necessarily wrong with using an older book, a lot has changed since then, and I'd encourage you to find something more recent.

Comment: To your problem, make sure PHP (and possibly MySQL) error handling is turned on. During development, I'd usually recommend avoiding `try` statements, they tend to hide bugs more than anything. Every `if` has an ultimate `else`, and if you don't handle that errors can creep in there. Lastly, this code has a bunch of magic functions defined elsewhere that we can't see the contents of. Start much smaller. Skip what the site looks like completely and just build a simple form that makes an HTTP post, then work on sessions, then add a database, and keep expanding once you get a general concept

Comment: It was published in 2017

Comment: I'm not smart enough to write the code. Please help me log in automatically by generating a session

Comment: I apologize for the publication date, it felt like it was the book _PHP and MySQL Web Development_. As to "I'm not smart enough to write the code", I also apologize for not being able to help you, and unfortunately SO isn't the place for teaching people to write code, or to write code for them.

Comment: The php error log should contain an errors. Read these and think about what exactly they say.

Comment: There are no errors in the error log file. When I copy and paste the link to the URL bar it logs me in but if I press the Login button after registration there is a problem. Someone please help me.